# Отладка ollydbg для взлома

Tags: dll, zip, reverse-engineering

Есть программа, использующая в процессе работы запароленный zip-архив (там хранятся его его ресурсы). Хочу изменить и обратно запаковать.

Программа сама их распаковывает во временные, и оттуда можно взять и изменить сами ресурсы. Но обратно не запаковать без пароля. `Plaintext attack` (ведь сами исходные файлы доступны) ничего не смогла расшифровать пароль, хотя пыталась (атака продолжалась) 1 день и 6 часов. Раз сама программа распаковывает, значит пароль хранится (где-то в ней). Хотя до этого она просится в инет, я не думаю, что это имеет значения.

Распаковка идет через отдельную библиотеку (dll), а значит пароль (даже если полученный с сервера) передается этой библиотеке при вызове. Как можно отловить этот мемент и где искать при этом пароль. Я никогда этого не делал, поэтому взял `OllyDbg`, как простой дебаггер. Есть ли смысл заморачиваться (реально ли дебаггером отловить пароль)? И где искать (в каком направлении рыть) (я думаю, перед вызовом пароль должен лежать в регистрах).

Comment: Рыть в сторону изучения DLL: в первую очередь смотреть что там за экспорты и которые из них могут применяться для распаковки.

Comment: найти названия экспорт. ф-ий нетрудно. Найти вызовы, наверное, тоже нетрудно будет (через _call_, наверное, будет). Меня интересует, где искать передаваемые в аргументах данные (я думаю, пасс передается через аргументы)? Или пароль библиотеку можно передать по-другому (кроме вызова функции из библиотеки и передачи напрямую аргументов).

Comment: Вы бы для начала нашли нужную функцию, гадать можете до посинения, пока не найдете ее.